# Mocking the FireDAC

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, firedac, dunit

I just entered the Delphi's Unit Testing area - never have done it in Delphi. The things went fine until I came to database connection and queries. I am using `TFDConnection` and `TFDQuery` in data access classes.

I found [an article](http://www.nickhodges.com/post/Delphi-Mocks-The-Basics.aspx) stating that for "expensive" calls interfaces should be used. I looked into FireDAC's source code and haven't found any suitable interface that I could use. And the perspective to implement most of FireDAC's behaviour doesn't cheer me up.

How to do mocking database objects the right way?

I am starting to think that pointing the system to test database should be much easier.

Comment: I have always read that you shouldn't have unit tests connected to a database, your approach (mocks) could solve those issues, getting repeatable responses. I'm looking for what the experts think of it.